# Autocomplete list for streets within a specific city

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Is it possible to create an Autocomplete list, when we pass the city name to google map?

For example if I set city name to `'Frankfurt'` and if the user starts typing in a street Autocomplete box, he/she sees only the streets list within `'Frankfurt'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really restrict the autocomplete suggestion to a city, but you can give it bounds so that any suggestion gets biased towards that rectangle.

For example

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchfield');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

autocomplete.setBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.05, 8.35), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.20, 9.02)
    )
);
```

would bias the suggestion towards that rectangle, but if you enter Las Vegas will still suggest Las Vegas, Nevada. Bias isn't enough to outright discard obvious suggestions.

Besides that, there's only the `setComponentRestrictions` method, but it only lets you specify the country, not a city.